# Pause a task in a timer on when pausing game on libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

How do I pause task in timer when game is paused on libgdx? when I pause the game. All animations stop, but the timer keeps run its sceduled task.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Timer.stop()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html#stop%28%29) will "pause" the timer, and [.start()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html#start%28%29) will resume calculating the delays (odd that they're not called "pause" and "resume", though).  You'll want to call these in your ApplicationListener's `pause` and `resume` callbacks.

If you're using the static `Timer.schedule()` methods, you'll want to stop/start the [`Timer.instance`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html#instance) static public instance.